# The name 'EncryptStringToBytes_Aes' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone beginner here.

I checked the AES tutorial at [Windows Phone AesManaged Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and tried the sample in my sample project.

I couldn't get it working and it kept giving the error

> The name 'EncryptStringToBytes_Aes' does not exist in the current
>   context

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace myProject.Services
{
    class Encrypter
    {
        public static string encryptMessage(String message)
        {
            string cryptex = null;

            try
            {
                using (AesManaged theAes = new AesManaged())
                {
                    byte[] encryptedStream = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(message, theAes.Key, theAes.IV);

                    cryptex = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedStream, 0, encryptedStream.Count());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            return cryptex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the EncryptStringToBytes_Aes method? As shown in the tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes - the page you linked to includes the `EncryptStringToBytes_Aes` method in the sample code - but you omitted it when you copied it, for some reason. It's just under the `Demo` method...

```
static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was the case! I wish I had checked it earlier. 

Thanks for the help.